# Is it possible to stop aging process completely?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, humans, time

Can you propose a System where it Will be possible to stop the aging process?

Simply put, can any one propose a mechanism/principle/theory?

OR

A reference where something like this has been mentioned by someone which can stop aging?

Comment: Since he won't make his big discovery for 20 years, Von Lehman is probably still in high school...

Comment: "Von Lehman’s Principle of Electron Compression on Deoxyribonucleic Acid" - pseudo-science as plot device.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is not about worldbuilding. You might try taking it to the [Movies.SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: The problem is that "Electron Compression on Deoxyribonucleic Acid" does not exist. If the question is "could something like that exist in the future" is too speculative.

Comment: @knave Just because i have referenced movie. It doesn't mean that it should be Movies section. Movie is just "metaphorical" reference. I found this topic fit and interesting for this community, therefore i posted it here

Comment: Alex if you reword this question to propose a system by which people do not age as opposed to asking if it is possible somehow or somewhen, I think the question could be reopened.  Feel free to visit chat if you want to discuss further.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: @James Thanks a ton for your advice. I have re-edited it. :)

Comment: is magic and pseudo-science allowed or only scientific explanations?

Comment: @Vincent seudo-science or scientific explanations will do :)

Answer (score 4):

If by "is it possible," you mean "merely developing a way to stop genetic clocks," sure.  If you mean that would be construed as "not aging," no.  That is movie magic.

There are genetic clocks that govern aging, such as telomeres. Telomeres, in particular, are believed to be essential for stopping cancer, so anyone who can repair them would be rife for cancer issues in their life.  In fact, one of the first steps many cancers undergo in their life is to upregulate the genes for telemerase, which allows the cancer cell to reproduce without hitting this genetic clock.

However, there are many other factors to aging.  In particular, physical trauma is cumulative.  While the human body is very good at undoing damage, it isn't perfect.  Some things are simply beyond its capabilities.  When we are young (i.e. still a fetus), the gaps that one may need to cover for a trauma are small.  Once one is 5 foot or 6 foot tall, the distances to be traveled are much further.

One particular source of aging that is outside the scope of genetics is scarring.  We scar whenever our skin cannot recover fast enough.  Once a scar is created, its very hard to undo them.

Now what is possible is to look surprisingly young for a long time.  Consider the active people in their 80s who look like they're 45.  It's totally doable, but its less to do with an invented concept of electron compression, and more to do with just taking good care of your body, inside and out.

Comment: That's good explanation. Well, i don't have much base in chemistry, coz I am computer science guy myself. But, do you think it is possible using "Electron degeneracy pressure"?

Comment: In my opinion, it is not possible, simply because I am aware of no scientific meaning for that phrase at all.  It appears to be purely tech speak, where a writer glued a few words together for a script.  On the other hand, because it has no meaning, it would be possible simply by finding a process to stop aging and assigning it the name "electron degeneracy pressure."  (Perhaps that's cheating, though)

Comment: @CortAmmon: [Electron degeneracy pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_degeneracy_pressure) is totally a thing. It is what keeps [white dwarfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_dwarf) from collapsing. (White dwarfs are a type of star, not remarkably short caucasian people.) Applying it to anti-aging treatment is left as an exercise.